# How safe are downloadable lock apps?

Tags: lock-screens, security

I've noticed quite a few [lock screen apps](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-lock-screen-apps-lock-screen-replacement-apps-565514/) and some of them do seem to be rather interesting.

But, are they really that secure? I've seen some where I can bypass them by using the Recently Opened Apps list. I've also noticed that some of them show whatever was previously up when I turn my phone on again.

These shortcomings seem to imply that they're very easily circumvented. Is this true and is there a way to make them more secure?

Comment: To put it simply, we have to go back to basic: do you trust the developer of the lock screen apps? Take note that different Android version may give different behavior, and the developer doesn't/haven't tested them, so it might be a case of bug. And lastly, to make them more secure, give your feedback to the dev when you find the security hole!

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Some are secure while most are insecure. For example there are finger print apps. Most of the people knows the trick so its insecure.

Comment: Pressing home button also bypasses app

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you must have a different lock screen than the stock one available on your device, there is certainly a degree of insecurity. I used WidgetLocker for a few years on two HTC devices and it worked perfectly, but installed on a Samsung Galaxy S3 the app would unlock with a simple press of the home button.

It really does depend on the device you have as well as the app. You might be better off searching the web for instances where users have your device and what apps they specifically recommend.